# Name of the currently displayed layout from the alias resource file

Tags: android

I've got three alias resource files supporting different sizes and orientations with the same, but different layout names e.g

```
<resources>
   <item name="main_act_res" type="layout">@layout/main_act_h</item>
</resources>

<resources>
   <item name="main_act_res" type="layout">@layout/main_act_v</item>
</resources>
```

Each layout has a FrameLayout container for a fragment that must know which layout is currently displayed in order to fetch an image with the correct orientation.

The code I use in fragment will always get an alias name (main_act_res), instead of the layout name (e.g main_act_h)

```
val layoutName = activity?.resources?.getResourceEntryName(R.layout.main_act_res)
```

I tried getting resource id first and then name, but I'm getting "Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff" exceptlion error.

```
val layoutId = activity?.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)?.rootView?.id
    val layoutName = layoutId?.let { activity?.resources?.getResourceEntryName(it) }
```

What is the correct way to get the currently displayed activity layout in this case?

Comment: Off the cuff, I think you should be able to get that with `Resources#getValue()`. Something like `val out = TypedValue()`, `activity?.resources?.getValue(R.layout.main_act_res, out, true)`. The current resolved numerical value should be in `out.resourceId`. You could just compare that value to `R.layout.main_act_h`, `R.layout.main_act_v`, etc., to see which one it is, but if you really need the name, then `getResourceEntryName(out.resourceId)`.

Comment: It works. I will put the code below to keep code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mike M. suggestion in the comment, I was able to retrieve the name of the current activity layout with the following code:

```
val out = TypedValue()
activity?.resources?.getValue(R.layout.main_act_res, out, true)
val layoutId = out.resourceId
layoutName = activity?.resources?.getResourceEntryName(layoutId)
```